# Working with Dropdowns in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I need a dropdown to be inaccessible (in can be visible or not, but preferably invisible).  What approach would you take?
I’m using C#, ASP.NET MVC 5, and the Razor syntax.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Please give samples of what you tried already

Comment: CCH Thanks for following up on my questions.  I haven't tried anything.  My question is asking for "your" approach.  Trying an approach I choose would pretty much make my question obsolete.  Thank you though.

Comment: @user3570351 You are asked to give samples of what you tried so that people don't have to figure out at what level you are stuck. Imagine someone answering and you stating "I already tried that".

Comment: @Modus Tollens  Reasonable, but that was not what my question asked.  I asked for the responders approach.  I was not getting errors or was stuck on how to implement a specific solution.  I am a beginner with MVC and Razor.  I was seeking for the opinion of the expertise of someone who is not a beginner.  Thanks for trying to explain it to me though.

Comment: I'd still like to know why my question was down voted.  It's a valid question, and in the right location.  I noticed my original comment on this has been censored.  Was that question out of line or something?  If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit abstract since you're just asking in the general sense.  In Razor, I'd evaluate the condition that determines if it should be shown or not and then within the "if" block, put the code to build the dropdown.

```
@if (showDropdown){
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyField, MySelectList)
}
else
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MyField)
}
```

If we want the value to of MyField to stick around when I post the form, then use a hidden field for the value when the dropdown is supposed to be invisible.

Comment: Thank you padotj.  You are right, my question is a bit abstract, but isn't that what we programmers love--abstractness?  :)  This was exactly what I was looking for and it works very well.  I am very new to MVC and Razor, so guidance from an expert is what I was after.